# Double Menu Item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks

I am using Serenity MVC framework. I ve add menu items inside NavigationItems.cs. After build my project and i see double Student link.

```
[assembly: NavigationMenu(8900, "StudentMain", icon: "icon-anchor")]
[assembly: NavigationLink(8910, "StudentMain/Student", typeof(StudentIN.StudentMain.Pages.StudentController), icon: "icon-wallet")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergen (code generator) generated a NavigationLink attribute in your StudentPage.cs.

Probably you added a new navigation link to NavigationItems.cs manually and forgot to move / delete one on top of StudentPage.cs. Just remove it.